# PHP: Best Way To Determine Position In Array

Tags: php

### What I Wish To Implement

My site does a nightly API data fetch, inserting 100,000+ new entries each night. To save space, each field name is in a seperate table with an allocated ID saving around 1,027 bytes per data set, 2.5675MB approx per night and just under a gigabyte over the course of a year, however this is set to increase.

For each user, a JSON file is requested containing the 112 entries to be added. Instead of checking my table for each name ID, I feel to save time, it would be best to create an array whereas the position in the array will be the ID, so lets use some random vegetable names;

**Random List Of Vegetables**

```
"Broccoli", "Brussels sprouts", "Cabbage", "Calabrese", "Carrots", "Cauliflower", "Celery", "Chard", "Collard greens", "Corn salad", "Endive", "Fiddleheads (young coiled fern leaves)", "Frisee", "Fennel"
```

When I create the insert via my PHP classes, I use the following;

```
$database->bind(':veg_name', VALUE);
```

### Question

What would be the *best* method to quickly check what position `$x` is within the array?

Comment: Personally I would delegate that matching process to the database. First, insert your raw data into a (temporary) table. Then run an SQL query to fetch the respective IDs and insert all entries to your fact table.

Comment: What is meant by `$x`?

Comment: @Sirko can you please elaborate? So each night for each user, there are 122 new entries to be added to the table or a historical log. I plan for the `User_ID`, `Field_ID` and `Timestamp` to be the Primary Key.

Comment: @m13r `$X` is the `Field_Nmae` obtained from the fetched `JSON`, so in my example, it could be `Carrots`.

Comment: @TimMarshall I added an answer detailing my suggestion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As an alternative solution to matching the entries in PHP (which might at some point run into time and/or memory problems):

The general idea is to let the database to the work. It is already optimized (index structures) to match entries to one another.

So following your example, the database probably has a dimensional table for the field names `fields`:

```
ID | Name
---------------------------------
0  | "Broccoli"
1  | "Brussels sprouts"
2  | "Cabbage"
```

Then there is the "final" table `facts`, which has a structure like this:

```
User_ID | Field_ID | Timestamp
```

Now a new batch of entries should be inserted. For this, we first create a temporary table `temp` with the following format and insert all raw entries. The last column `Field_ID` will stay empty for now.

```
User_ID | Field_Name | Timestamp | Field_ID
```

In a next step we match each field name with its ID using a simple SQL query:

```
UPDATE `temp` t
SET Field_ID=(SELECT Field_ID FROM fields f WHERE f.Name=t.Field_Name)
```

So now the database has done our required mapping and we can issue another query to insert the rows into our fact table:

```
INSERT INTO facts
SELECT User_ID, Field_ID, Timestamp FROM temp WHERE Field_ID IS NOT NULL
```

A small side-effect here: All rows in our `temp` table, that could not be matched (we didn't have the field name in our `fields` table), are still available there. So we could write some logic to send an error report somewhere and have someone add the field names or otherwise fix the issue.

After we are done, we should remove or at least truncate the `temp` table to be ready for next nights iteration.

---

Small remark: The queries here are just examples. You could do the mapping and insertion into your `facts` table in one query, but then you'd lose the "unmatched" entries or have to redo the work.

Redoing the work might not be an issue now, but you said the number of entries will increase in the future, so this might become an issue.

Comment: This is absolutely fantastic, however I'm not entirely sure whether or not I am currently skilled enough to achieve what you have mentioned. Yes, indeed the entries will increase, this is based on how many users are on the site with a valid API key, of which I estimate anywhere between 5,00 to 10,000 1-2 months after launch. After 3 days, when the "bounty" option is available, I am going to reward you with additional points. After going thought what you have said several times, I will make an attempt then update here in whcih I do hope you will be able to assist further. Thank you.

Comment: Should my temporary table be local `#table_name` or global `##table_name` and does this table need a primary key?

Comment: The conventions for temporary tables depend on the DBMS you're using. You didn't mention one (afaik). Regarding the primary key: I don't think you need one. All queries will run over all rows in that table anyways, so there is nothing to gain, I think.

Comment: I've got the 1&1 Cloud Server running Plesk and using PHPMyAdmin

Answer (score 1):

If you're only doing 2.5 megs/night, that's almost nothing. If you gzipped that before dragging it across, it would reduce it a lot more.

Using array positions could get tricky if you're trying to use that to match something in some other table.

That being said, every array has a numeric index as well, so you can find out what that is at any point.

Try this and you'll see:

```
$array = array("Broccoli", "Brussels sprouts", "Cabbage", "Calabrese", "Carrots", "Cauliflower", "Celery", "Chard", "Collard greens", "Corn salad", "Endive", "Fiddleheads (young coiled fern leaves)", "Frisee", "Fennel");

var_dump(array_keys($array));
```

On the array, you can also do this:

```
$currentKey = array_search("carrot",$array);
```

That will return the key for a given variable. So if you're looping through an array, you can output the key(index) and go do something else with it.

Also, gzip is a form of compression that makes your data much smaller.

Comment: Can you please elaborate? So each night for each user, there are 122 new entries to be added to the table or a historical log. I plan for the `User_ID`, `Field_ID` and `Timestamp` to be the Primary Key. I'm not sure on what you mean by `gzipped ` and you don't explain how to find what the likes of `$X` position in the `array()` is?

Comment: I updated my answer. Does that help?

Answer (score 0):

If you have a list of item, e.g. an array containing only strings that represent your values, you can use `foreach` with a key-value (`$users as $index => $user`) method instead of just a `$users as $user` like following :

```
$users = ["Broccoli", "Brussels sprouts", "Cabbage", "Calabrese", "Carrots", "Cauliflower", "Celery", "Chard", "Collard greens", "Corn salad", "Endive", "Fiddleheads (young coiled fern leaves)", "Frisee", "Fennel"];

foreach( $users as $index => $name ) {
  echo "about to insert $name which is the #$index..." . PHP_EOL;
}
```

Which will echo :

> about to insert Broccoli which is the #0...
>
> about to insert Brussels sprouts which is the #1...
>
> about to insert Cabbage which is the #2...
>
> about to insert Calabrese which is the #3...
>
> about to insert Carrots which is the #4...
>
> about to insert Cauliflower which is the #5...
>
> about to insert Celery which is the #6...
>
> about to insert Chard which is the #7...
>
> about to insert Collard greens which is the #8...
>
> about to insert Corn salad which is the #9...
>
> about to insert Endive which is the #10...
>
> about to insert Fiddleheads (young coiled fern leaves) which is the #11...
>
> about to insert Frisee which is the #12...
>
> about to insert Fennel which is the #13...

Live-example available here : https://repl.it/Jpwk

Like @m13r asked, how would an index be useful in your case ?